# jquery wont set image src from another image

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web, weebly

I have started some blogs using Weebly now I want to do several changes to the blog UI, everything went well until I wanted to do this. I wanted to get the image path from the image inside **blog-content** and set it on the **blog-post-image**. In my head, this jquery looks logical, but somewhere error lays.

Few things to care about, I should use **each** because there are many of the blog posts and I cannot use ids because of the same reason, cannot use the same id multiple times.

HTML:

```js
$('.blog-post-image').each(function() {
  var $me = $(this);
  var blogPostImage = $me.siblings('.blog-content').children('img').attr('src');

  $me.attr('src', blogPostImage);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="blog-post-746510653886732592" class="blog-post">
  <div class="blog-header">
    <div class="blog-post-container">
      <h2 class="blog-title">
      </h2>
      <p class="blog-date">
        <span class="date-text">
        15/6/2021
        </span>
      </p>
      <div>

        <img class="blog-post-image" />

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="blog-content">
    <div>
      <div class="wsite-image wsite-image-border-none " style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;margin-left:0;margin-right:0;text-align:center">
        <a>
          <img src="/uploads/7/7/9/0/77909082/820610853.jpg" alt="Picture" style="width:100%;max-width:1100px">
        </a>
        <div style="display:block;font-size:90%">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `.blog-content` isn't a sibling of `.blog-post-image`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1.) `.blog-content` is not a sibling of `.blog-post-image`

2.) `.children()` only looks one level deep to find the element you are looking for.

What you need to do is traverse upwards to find a sibling of `.blog-content` and then use the `.find()` function to do a deep search of the given DOM node to find what you're looking for.

```js
$('.blog-post-image').each(function() {
  var me = $(this);
  var blogPostImage = me.parent().parent().parent().siblings('.blog-content').find('img').attr('src');
  me.attr('src', blogPostImage);
});
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="blog-post-746510653886732592" class="blog-post">
    <div class="blog-header">
      <div class="blog-post-container">
        <h2 class="blog-title">
        </h2>
        <p class="blog-date">
          <span class="date-text">15/6/2021</span>
        </p>
        <div>
          <img class="blog-post-image" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blog-content">
      <div>
        <div class="wsite-image wsite-image-border-none " style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;margin-left:0;margin-right:0;text-align:center">
          <a>
            <img src="/uploads/7/7/9/0/77909082/820610853.jpg" alt="Picture" style="width:100%;max-width:1100px">
          </a>
          <div style="display:block;font-size:90%">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, same as in above answer comments, I am not able to make it works. This weebly is complete nightmare.

Comment: @DanijelMarkov what issue is it giving you? Do you get any console errors?

Comment: Both working, I have solve the issue. Header was a problem

Answer (score 2):

`.blog-post-image` doesn't have any siblings. Siblings are immediate children of the same parent element, but there are no other elements in the `div` containing `<img class="blog-post-image" />`.

You need to go up to the `.blog-header` to get its sibling.

Also, instead of using `.each()`, you can use a function in `.attr()`. It automatically loops, and assigns the return value to the attribute.

```js
$('.blog-post-image').attr('src', function() {
  return $(this).closest('.blog-header').siblings('.blog-content').find('img').attr('src');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="blog-post-746510653886732592" class="blog-post">
  <div class="blog-header">
    <div class="blog-post-container">
      <h2 class="blog-title">
      </h2>
      <p class="blog-date">
        <span class="date-text">
        15/6/2021
        </span>
      </p>
      <div>

        <img class="blog-post-image" />

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="blog-content">
    <div>
      <div class="wsite-image wsite-image-border-none " style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;margin-left:0;margin-right:0;text-align:center">
        <a>
          <img src="/uploads/7/7/9/0/77909082/820610853.jpg" alt="Picture" style="width:100%;max-width:1100px">
        </a>
        <div style="display:block;font-size:90%">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your solution is better than mine :)

Comment: Except I didn't fix `.children()`.

Comment: No biggy. Good solution. You need to change that to find. It's missing the top header image.

Comment: Just tried your and solution below.


Here is the [Blog](https://www.paget96projects.com/blog)
 link so check it, maybe is there something else that I have missed.

Comment: Seems that even   ```$('.blog-post-image').attr('src', "https://www.paget96projects.com/uploads/7/7/9/0/77909082/editor/p96-1-3.jpg?1623063371");```
Wont work

Comment: Both working, I have solve the issue. Header was a problem. Thanks for the time guys